# How to detach the wires from a HY29E toggle switch?

Tags: switch

I am trying to replace HY29E toggle switch.  The one in the pic is stuck (cannot be turned on).

I am not able to detach the wires from the switch.  I have watched a few videos but the wire terminals in the video aren't similar to these (and I don't know what these are called).

I tried holding the white plastic terminal and pulling it away from the switch but couldn't budge it.

Here is the image:
[image]

Is there a trick to detaching the wires?  Is there a reason for these special wire terminals?

---

In case it helps the switch is part of a coffee making machine.

Comment: Make/model of the coffee maker?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Male spade connectors often have a dimple or hole in the center, and the female will have a tab or bump that engages the hole. This makes them more secure and less likely to vibrate off.

Two good suggestions were provided as comments:

- Grab the connector base with a pliers and pull as you wiggle.
- Slip a flat screwdriver under the base and pry upward.

Be gentle with any technique. Some of that plastic is fairly hard and will crack under heavy handling.

[image]

Comment: this image may be clearer ..https://az343058.vo.msecnd.net/productlargeimages/c5bf55bd1f7a476d9fde50e48bb826ed.jpg.

Comment: Feel free to edit it right on in.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a split pry tool or lacking one, a strong fork to lever the plugs off the lugs from underneath.  Worse case, you break something but I wouldn't care because my next step would be to cut the plugs off and install new ones, and if the wires aren't long enough to possibly replace them entirely from both ends.